# What does TypeError: 'OAuth2FlowNoRedirectResult' object is not iterable mean

Tags: python-3.x, dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox python extension and i get this error message:

```
TypeError: 'OAuth2FlowNoRedirectResult' object is not iterable
```

this is the code so far:

```
import dropbox
flow = dropbox.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)

# Have the user sign in and authorize this token
authorize_url = flow.start()
print ('1. Go to: ' + authorize_url)
print ('2. Click "Allow" (you might have to log in first)')
print ('3. Copy the authorization code.')
code = input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()

# This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code
access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)

f = open('Top Secret.jpg', 'rb')
response = client.put_file('Top Secret.jpg', f)
print ("uploaded:", response)
f.close()

f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/Top Secret.jpg')
out = open('Test.jpg', 'wb')
out.write(f.read())
out.close()
print (metadata)
```

i excluded the app key and the app secret for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be in this line:

```
access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)
```

The [`DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.finish`](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.oauth.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.finish) method there returns a single [`OAuth2FlowNoRedirectResult`](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.oauth.OAuth2FlowNoRedirectResult) object. You're trying to unpack to a tuple though (`access_token, user_id`), effectively trying to iterate over it to do so, which fails because there isn't anything else to iterate over.

There's some sample code showing how to use the [`DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.finish`](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.oauth.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.finish) in the documentation for [`DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect`](http://[%60DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.finish%60][1]).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following lines of code as follows -

```
access_token,user_id= flow.finish(code)
```

to

```
access_token= flow.finish(code)
```

The

> flow.finish

method does not return a tuple . It returns a single object .